# Hadoop Mapreduce Counters

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

Can Anyone explain in detail the meaning of following File System counters?

- FILE_BYTES_READ
- FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN
- FILE_READ_OPS
- FILE_LARGE_READ_OPS
- FILE_WRITE_OPS
- HDFS_BYTES_READ
- HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN
- HDFS_READ_OPS
- HDFS_LARGE_READ_OPS
- HDFS_WRITE_OPS

Comment: Do you know how to enter queries in Google? Information is at your finger tips. Why'd you ask it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FILE_BYTES_READ** is the **number of bytes read by local file system**. Assume all the map input data comes from HDFS, then in map phase FILE_BYTES_READ should be zero. On the other hand, the input file of reducers are data on the reduce-side local disks which are fetched from map-side disks. Therefore, FILE_BYTES_READ denotes the total bytes read by reducers.

**FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN** consists of two parts. The first part comes from mappers. All the mappers will spill intermediate output to disk. All the bytes that mappers write to disk will be included in FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN. The second part comes from reducers. In the shuffle phase, all the reducers will fetch intermediate data from mappers and merge and spill to reducer-side disks. All the bytes that reducers write to disk will also be included in FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN.

**HDFS_BYTES_READ** denotes the bytes read by mappers from HDFS when the job starts. This data includes not only the content of source file but also meta data about splits.

**HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN** denotes the bytes written to HDFS. It’s the number of bytes of the final output.

**read operations** - number of read operations such as listStatus, getFileBlockLocations, open etc.

**write operations** - number of write operations such as create, append, setPermission etc.

*http://comphadoop.weebly.com/experiment-and-results.html*